# How can I access the time zone identifier on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, datetime, timezone

The `TimeZoneInfo.Id` property appears to be unsupported on Windows Phone. How can I access the official [time zone (TZ) identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) on Windows Phone? For example, "America/Los_Angeles".

The `TimeZoneInfo.StandardName` property returns "Pacific Standard Time", which is not the TZ identifier. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not provide TZ values directly, for example through the TimeZoneInfo class. You could use the [ZoneInfo (tz Database / Olson Database) .NET API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/zoneinfo_dotnet_api.aspx) to look up the TZ value.

Comment: I don't see an available download for this API. Has it been moved?

Comment: Gosh, I'm surprised there's no download. Here's an artile on [How to Use the Olson Time Zone Database in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Using_time_zones_in_NET.aspx) that I think should get you the same thing.

Comment: This version isn't compatible with the Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: Dang it. If I had a few hours, it'd be fun to try porting the small portion you need. I'm in crunch mode getting ready for a go-live. Have you looked at the source code or thought about what that would take? What's your timeframe on getting this resolved?

Comment: Thank you for the offer! I came up with a workaround. Microsoft maps standard time zone names to time zone identifiers. The TimeZoneInfo class has a property for the standard time zone name. So, now I can perform a simple lookup. 

The Windows time zone mappings can be found here: http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html Thank you again.